# A literary structure

Tags: subjunctive-mood, literary-techniques

> Prais’d be the fathomless universe,
>
> For life and joy, and for objects and knowledge curious,

Does the first sentence means "praise is for fathomless universe"? Is it an old structure?

Comment: See "subjunctive" https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subjunctive_mood ... This means "May the fathomless universe be praised".  But it is still "be" for subjunctive, not "is" for indicative.

Comment: "Praised be the fathomless universe"

Answer (score 1):

Today, *praise be* is an idiom used to give thanks for something. From [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/praise%20be):

> —used to say that one is glad or thankful about something

In this case, Walt Whitman is giving thanks to the fathomless universe for the reasons he lists in the second quoted line.

In form, it is an inversion of the common formula, "God be praised" ("Praised be God," or "praised be the universe," or "praised be nachos") which is itself an old-fashioned subjunctive. The *[American Etymological School Grammar](https://books.google.com/books?id=QyqsOoXFZ2IC&pg=PA43&lpg=PA43&dq=%22Praised%20be%22%20and%20%22be%20praised%22&source=bl&ots=4N7pqA7_Vu&sig=ACfU3U1QIVypCWjUoZQC83S2ZTiKUSQvcw&hl=en&ppis=_e&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjm0eOPzO_mAhWqm-AKHVkiCUUQ6AEwHHoECA0QAQ#v=onepage&q&f=false)* from 1853 felicitously includes an example conjugation of *to praise* to illustrate this - "I be praised," and so on are all marked the "ancient or poetic form" of the subjunctive, a label that fits Whitman's usage.